# Default parameter for CancellationToken

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, cancellation-token

I have some async code that I would like to add a `CancellationToken` to. However, there are many implementations where this is not needed so I would like to have a default parameter - perhaps `CancellationToken.None`. However,

```cs
Task<x> DoStuff(...., CancellationToken ct = null)
```

yields

> A value of type '<null>' cannot be used as a default parameter because
> there are no standard conversions to type
> 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'

and

```cs
Task<x> DoStuff(...., CancellationToken ct = CancellationToken.None)
```

> Default parameter value for 'ct' must be a compile-time constant

Is there any way to have a default value for `CancellationToken`?

Comment: I've also seen `new CancellationToken()` which is exactly equivalent to `default` as CancellationToken is a struct.

Comment: Why would anybody want this? it is easy to forget to pass `CancelationToken` even if you have it in the calling method, on the other hand it is not that hard to type `CancellationToken.None` in case you dont have it?

Answer (score 255):

It turns out that the following works:

```
Task<x> DoStuff(...., CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
```

...or:

```
Task<x> DoStuff(...., CancellationToken ct = default) // C# 7.1 and later
```

which, [according to the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none?view=netstandard-2.0#remarks), is interpreted the same as `CancellationToken.None`:

> You can also use the C# `default(CancellationToken)` statement to create
> an empty cancellation token.

Comment: This is exactly what the [framework *currently* does](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/CancellationToken.cs#ec32c41597007382) internally, but I would *not* do it in my code. Think what happens with your code if Microsoft change their implementation, and `CancellationToken.None` becomes something more than `default(CancellationToken)`.

Comment: @Noseratio That would break backwards compatibility in a big way, so I wouldn't expect that to happen. And what else would `default(CancellationToken)` do?

Comment: @svick, if my library references `System.Threading.CancellationToken.None` property, and the value of `CancellationToken.None` changes in a future version of mscorlib.dll, how would that break my library (the IL code)? I would not make predictions about `default(CancellationToken)` though.

Comment: @Noseratio If your library uses `default(CancellationToken)` (or `new CancellationToken()`), which I think is a valid thing to do for any value type, and that value started behaving differently, then that would break compatibility.

Comment: @svick, I see your point, but nowhere on MSDN it is mentioned that `CancellationToken.None` *is* the same thing as `default(CancellationToken)`. Technically it may become a `static readonly` struct with non-default fields, unlikely but possible. Then if my library used `CancellationToken.None`, I'd stay compatible. Not so if it used `default(CancellationToken)`.

Comment: @Noseratio: You're being too rigid. Chances are `CancellationToken.None` will become de facto deprecated. Even Microsoft is using `default(CancellationToken)` instead. For example, see [these search results](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/search?q=default%28CancellationToken%29) from the source code of the Entity Framework.

Comment: From MSDN [CancellationToken.None Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780763(v=vs.110).aspx): _"You can also use the C# default(CancellationToken) statement to create an empty cancellation token"_. None is a mistake until a futur version of C# accept it as default parameter.

Comment: Same [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) _To compensate for the two missing intermediate combinations, developers may pass None or a default CancellationToken for the cancellationToken parameter and null for the progress parameter._

Answer (score 29):

Here are several solutions, in descending order of general goodness:

#### 1. Using `default(CancellationToken)` as default value:

```
Task DoAsync(CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken)) { … }
```

Semantically, `CancellationToken.None` would be the ideal candidate for the default, but cannot be used as such because it isn't a compile-time constant. `default(CancellationToken)` is the next best thing because it is a compile-time constant and [officially documented to be equivalent to `CancellationToken.None`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.none.aspx).

#### 2. Providing a method overload without a `CancellationToken` parameter:

Or, if you prefer method overloads over optional parameters (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251868/should-you-declare-methods-using-overloads-or-optional-parameters-in-c-sharp-4-0) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3316402/method-overloading-vs-optional-parameter-in-c-sharp-4-0) question on that topic):

```
Task DoAsync(CancellationToken ct) { … } // actual method always requires a token
Task DoAsync() => DoAsync(CancellationToken.None); // overload producing a default token
```

For interface methods, the same can be achieved using extension methods:

```
interface IFoo
{
    Task DoAsync(CancellationToken ct);
}

static class Foo
{
    public static Task DoAsync(this IFoo foo) => foo.DoAsync(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

This results in a slimmer interface and spares implementers from explicitly writing the forwarding method overload.

#### 3. Making the parameter nullable and using `null` as default value:

```
Task DoAsync(…, CancellationToken? ct = null)
{
    … ct ?? CancellationToken.None …
}
```

I like this solution least because nullable types come with a small runtime overhead, and references to the cancellation token become more verbose because of the null coalescing operator `??`.

Answer (score 26):

> Is there any way to have a default value for CancellationToken?

Unfortunately, this is not possible, as `CancellationToken.None` is not a compile time constant, which is a requirement for default values in optional arguments.

You can provide the same effect, however, by making an overloaded method instead of trying to use default parameters:

```
Task<x> DoStuff(...., CancellationToken ct)
{
    //...
}

Task<x> DoStuff(....)
{
    return DoStuff(...., CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: This is the recommended way to handle this, as explained on the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) documentation on MSDN (specifically in the section **Choosing the Overloads to Provide**).

Comment: CancellationToken.None == default
true

Comment: What's the matter with `CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)`? Also described here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/03/19/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/

Answer (score 11):

Another option is to use a `Nullable<CancellationToken>` parameter, default it to `null`, and deal with it inside the method:

```
Task<x> DoStuff(...., CancellationToken? ct = null) {
    var token = ct ?? CancellationToken.None;
    ...
}
```

Comment: brilliant!  by far this is the best answer

Comment: This is the same as providing default now c# 7.1 above. It's better to just use default.

Answer (score 11):

Newer versions of C# allow for a simplified syntax for the default(CancellationToken) version. E.g.:

```
Task<x> DoStuff(...., CancellationToken ct = default)
```