# Task behaviour differs from Task<T> behaviour when OperationCanceledException thrown

Tags: .net, unit-testing, task-parallel-library, task

Why does this test fail?
The only difference between `t1` and `t2`, as far as I can tell, is that `t1` is a `Task`, and `t2` is a `Task<int>`. Yet for some reason `t2` ends up in the `Faulted` status, as opposed to the `Canceled` status. Why would the behavior differ?

```
[Test]
public void Test_foo()
{
    var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    });
    try
    {
        t1.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(t1.IsCanceled);
    }

    var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
        return 1;
    });
    try
    {
        t2.Wait();
    }
    catch (AggregateException e)
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(t2.IsCanceled); // fails, it's Faulted 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between your tasks is the overload for the `Task.Run` method you're using:

`task1` is created with [`Task.Run Method (Func<Task>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382.aspx), rather than `task2` is created with [`Task.Run<TResult> Method (Func<TResult>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921.aspx). This overloads do create task with a little bit difference:

- for `task1` the [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) property is set to `System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult`, and [`CreationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.creationoptions.aspx) is set to `None`,
- rather than `task2` the [`CreationOptions`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.creationoptions.aspx) is set to `DenyChildAttach`, and the result is a `default(int)`, which is `0`.

When you are waiting the `task2`, the [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) property isn't being set to real value, because the exception is thrown. According [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx):

> When a task instance observes an [`OperationCanceledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) thrown by
>   user code, it compares the exception's token to its associated token
>   (the one that was passed to the API that created the `Task`). If they
>   are the same and the token's [`IsCancellationRequested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested.aspx) property returns
>   **true**, the task interprets this as acknowledging cancellation and
>   transitions to the `Canceled` state. If you do not use a [`Wait`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait.aspx) or [`WaitAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall.aspx)
>   method to wait for the task, then the task just sets its status to
>   `Canceled`.
>
> If you are waiting on a Task that transitions to the
>   `Canceled` state, a [`System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskcanceledexception.aspx)
>   exception (wrapped in an [`AggregateException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception.aspx) exception) is thrown. Note
>   that this exception indicates successful cancellation instead of a
>   faulty situation. Therefore, the task's [`Exception`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.exception.aspx) property returns
>   **null**.
>
> If the token's [`IsCancellationRequested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested.aspx) property returns `false` or
>   **if the exception's token does not match the Task's token**, the
>   [`OperationCanceledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) **is treated like a normal exception**, causing
>   the Task to transition to the `Faulted` state. Also note that the
>   presence of other exceptions will also cause the `Task` to transition to
>   the `Faulted` state. You can get the status of the completed task in the
>   [`Status`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.status.aspx) property.

So, here we can find the reason for this behavior - the exception is treated like a normal exception because of the token mismatch. This is strange, because the token is [definitely the same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22361135/213550) (I've checked that in Debug, the hash code is equal, `Equals` method and double equals operator returns `true`), but the comparison still returns `false`. So, the solution for your case is explicit usage of the [cancellation tokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.aspx), something like this (I've added the [`Thread.Sleep`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.sleep.aspx) to avoid the race condition):

```
var t1TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t1 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (t1TokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        t1TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    //throw new TaskCanceledException();
}, t1TokenSource.Token);
try
{
    t1TokenSource.Cancel();
    t1.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    Debug.Assert(t1.IsCanceled);
}

var t2TokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var t2 = Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    if (t2TokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        t2TokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
    //throw new TaskCanceledException();
    return 1;
}, t2TokenSource.Token);
try
{
    t2TokenSource.Cancel();
    t2.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    Debug.Assert(t2.IsCanceled);
}
```

Another quote from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx):

> You can terminate the operation by using one of these options:
>
> - By simply returning from the delegate. In many scenarios this is sufficient; however, a task instance that is canceled in this way
>     transitions to the `TaskStatus.RanToCompletion` state, not to the
>     `TaskStatus.Canceled` state.
> - By throwing a [`OperationCanceledException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.operationcanceledexception.aspx) and passing it the token on which cancellation was requested. **The preferred way to do this is
>     to use the [`ThrowIfCancellationRequested`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.throwifcancellationrequested.aspx) method.** A task that is
>     canceled in this way transitions to the `Canceled` state, which the
>     calling code can use to verify that the task responded to its
>     cancellation request.

As you can see, the preffered way is working predictably, the direct exception throw does not. Please also note that in case of usage `task` is created with `DenyChildAttach` too, and doesn't have a [`Result`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468.aspx) property, so there is some difference in constructors, which you've faced with.
Hope this helps.